# Unable to enter the Tomcat6-admin page after defining new role

Tags: apache, tomcat, tomcat6

I'm having problem in accessing the Tomcat6-admin web page, here's what I did:

```
##########################################################################################################
root@ISUZU:/etc/tomcat6# cat tomcat-users.xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<tomcat-users>
  <role rolename="tomcat"/>
  <role rolename="role1"/>
  **<role rolename="manager"/>
  <user username="admin" password="nimda" roles="manager"/>**
  <user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat"/>
  <user username="both" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat,role1"/>
  <user username="role1" password="tomcat" roles="role1"/>
</tomcat-users>
##########################################################################################################
root@ISUZU:/etc/tomcat6# /etc/init.d/tomcat6 restart
 * Stopping Tomcat servlet engine tomcat6                                                                                      [ OK ]
 * Starting Tomcat servlet engine tomcat6                                                                                             Using CATALINA_BASE:   /var/lib/tomcat6
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/share/tomcat6
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /tmp/tomcat6-tmp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/share/tomcat6/bin/bootstrap.jar
##########################################################################################################
```

The Hello World page is working fine from http://isuzu:8080/ but the admin page is still inaccessible.

Answer (score 3):

The admin application is not available at Tomcat 6. If you mean the manager application, then your tomcat-users.xml is correctly using the manager role. Check that the manager application isn't removed from the webapps directory.

Answer (score 2):

The correct rolename is admin for the admin gui, manager is for tomcat manager.

http://linux-sxs.org/internet_serving/c516.html